# what learning path experts suggests to magento2 begginer?

Tags: magento2

I am magento2 beginner and studied official documentation but find it difficult to understand it is request to experts to suggest me learning path with links of tutorials and pdf books for the strong base for magento2 coding career. That you think a beginner must know about.

Thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

As someone who walk in the same path as you are young padawan, I have some piece of advices.

- Don't ask this kind of issue in stackexchange or you will get banned and won't be able to come any more for the real issues you will find later^^

But still here are my answer.

- You need a very good comprehension of Object Oriented Programming.
- You need a very good comprehension of the patterns Model View Controller (MVC) and Factory.
- You need to accept the fact that to be able to do something by yourself you will need 6 month of practicing, and at least 1 year to be able to handle something complex alone.
- There is no hidden path, you can't learn magento in books you have to implement things. You will take the same wall 1,2,3,4 times....you won't understand what you are doing most of the time in the beginning. Step by steps you will understand why you take theses walls and you won't take then anymore.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a great advice